# Rewrite Rule which rewrites the intermediate path

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'd need to code a rewrite a rule so that articles from:

```
www.olddomain.com/categoryA/categoryB/article.html
```

are redirected to:

```
www.newdomain.com/categoryC/categoryD/article.html
```

So the challenge here is that the article.html page does not change from one site to another but the intermediate paths (categories) are different.
I've tried coding this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(categoryA/categoryB/.+)$ http://www.newdomain.com/categoryC/categoryD/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

However the Rule redirects from:

```
http://www.olddomain.com/categoryA/categoryB/article.html
```

to

```
http://www.newdomain.com/categoryC/categoryD/categoryA/categoryB/article.html
```

Can you suggest me a way to exclude the "old" category when performing the redirect? I'd expect to be redirected on:

```
http://www.newdomain.com/categoryC/categoryD/article.html
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this:

```
RewriteRule ^categoryA/categoryB/([^/]+)\.html$ http://www.newdomain.com/categoryC/categoryD/$1.html [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```